# asymptotic behavior of $N_{\mathbb{Q(\alpha)}/\mathbb{Q}} (1-\alpha^n)$

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, diophantine-approximation

We have an algebraic complex number $\alpha$ such that $|\alpha|=1$ and it is not a root of unity, We also know that $\alpha \in \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)}$ (ring of integers). I need to study the behavoir of $N_{\mathbb{Q(\alpha)}/\mathbb{Q}} (1-\alpha^n)$ when $n \rightarrow \infty $. Could someone give me a bibliographic reference?

Comment: What do you want to know about it? I'm assuming you don't want a reference for the definition...

Comment: It grows like $m(\alpha)^n$, where $m(\alpha)$ is the Mahler measure of (the minimal polynomial of) $\alpha$.

Comment: What do you mean by $|\alpha|=1$? There is no absolute value on algebraic numbers per se. You can embed the field of algebraic numbers into $\mathbb{C}$ in many ways, but in general different embeddings produce a different absolute value for a given algebraic number.

Comment: @Felipe: I think the powers of the Mahler measure give the right answer if no root of the polynomial lies on the unit circle. However, the question is about the case where one root lies on the unit circle. Isn't it possible to get a "strange" behaviour in this case? (Already: imagine $\alpha$ is a root of unity.)

Comment: @SteffenKionke As someone pointed out in a now-deleted comment (not sure why) the precise statement is that $\log(N(1-\alpha^n))/n$ converges to $m(\alpha)$ and it holds under the question's hypotheses, including when $\alpha$ is a root of unity.